# Observable with fixed maximum parell tasks using executors

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2, executorservice

I want to create an Observable which has can spawn a limited number task. For this I am trying to use an Executor service with blocking queue of a specific size. I am able to successfully test the expected behaviour of the executor (it accepts a maximum 8 parallel tasks. The test case is not included here).

But when I try to use the executor to restrict the maximum parallel tasks, I see that it is not happening. The test code below shows 100 immediate calls to `s.exec(t)`.

Is this the right way to restrict observables to a certain number of maximum tasks ?

**Thread Pool Code:**

```
public class ThreadPool {

    public static int MIN_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 1;
    public static int MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 2;
    public static int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 5;

    public static int SHUTDOWN_TIME = 30;

    // When the number of threads is greater than the core, this is the maximum time
    // that excess idle threads will wait for new tasks before terminating.
    public static int EXCESS_THREAD_KEEPALIVE_SEC = 30;

    // Rejected threads are run in the calling thread.
    // This blocks the calling thread from submitting more task.
    // So max tasks accepted will be (maxThreadPoolSize + maxQueueSize + 1)

    //Eagerly creating thread pool at startup
    public static BlockingQueue<Runnable> linkedBlockingDeque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);
    public static ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(MIN_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, EXCESS_THREAD_KEEPALIVE_SEC,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS, linkedBlockingDeque, new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
}
```

**Observable code**

```
public void execute(Task t, Service s) {

    Observable.just(t.getId())
        .doOnNext(
            input -> {
              logStartEvent(externalTask);
            })
        .map(x -> { 
           Thread.sleep(1000)//sleeping to simulate a long call
           return s.exec(t);
         })     
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(ThreadPool.executor))
        .subscribe(
            (response) -> {
              log.info(response.toString);
            },
            (error) -> {
                log.error(error.toString);
            }
    );

  }
```

**Test Code**

```
@Test
    public void testMutiThread() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    execute(externalTask, externalTaskService);
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have the `CallerRunsPolicy` which when the queue fills up due to `subscribeOn`, will execute the `s.exec(t)` right on those manual `Thread`s.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "Observable which has can spawn a limited number task"? Usually Observable does not spawn tasks. The code which named "Observable code" spawns tasks, but not as Observable (which is not yet created) but as the expressions which computes the argument for invocation of `Observable.just()`. This expression would spawn tasks even it would be used as a separate statement, without any call to `Observable.just()` or any other method.